# Get infeasibilities with IBM cplex feasopt python's interface

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, cplex

I am using IBM CPLEX python's API to solve a linear program.

The linear program I am solving turned out to be infeasible, so I am using feasopt() from CPLEX to relax the problem.

I could get a feasible solution through `my_prob.feasopt(my_prob.feasopt.all_constraints())`, where feasopt relaxes all the constraints.

But I am interested in getting the amount of relaxation for each constraint. Particularly, in the documentation it says `In addition to that conventional solution vector, FeasOpt also produces a vector of values that provide useful information about infeasible constraints and variables.`

I am interested in getting this vector.

Comment: This question was cross-posted on the IBM developerWorks forum [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=c6ecab52-d07a-421a-86ac-65a955da3034). I answered there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the methods available under the [Cplex.solution.infeasibility](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._subinterfaces.InfeasibilityInterface-class.html) interface.

Example usage:

```
# query the infeasibilities for all linear constraints
rowinfeas = my_prob.solution.infeasibility.linear_constraints(
    my_prob.solution.get_values())
```

Comment: Thanks, apologies for cross-posting.